# The probability of distributing $k$ balls over $n$ boxes with exactly $q$ boxes empty.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to solve this question and wound up with the following reasoning, but I'm not quite sure if it is correct.
The total number of possibilities of distribution $k$ balls over $n$ boxes can be given by $\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$. Now we need the possibilities to distribute $k$ balls over $n-q$ boxes,$\binom{k+n-q-1}{n-q-1}$ multiplied by the possible picks of $q$ boxes out of $n$,$\binom{n}{q}$. Thus resulting in $\binom{k+n-q-1}{n-q-1}\binom{n}{q}$. 
The total probability of exactly $q$ boxes remaining empty is then given by:
$$P = \frac{\binom{k+n-q-1}{n-q-1}\binom{n}{q}}{\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}}.$$
Is this the correct way of calculating this. I'm mostly unsure about the numerator.

Comment: You can tell that you first statement is wrong by considering the case $k=1$.

Comment: Also, you never formulate a problem anywhere. The title seems to hint at a counting problem but doesn't specify it. The penultimate sentence suddenly introduces probability in a setting where probability hadn't played any role before. Please clarify.

Comment: The balls are equal or different of each other?

Comment: The balls are identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the random protocol according to which the balls are distributed over the boxes. I shall assume the following: One ball after the other is thrown into one of the $n$ boxes, uniformly (i.e., all boxes have equal probability) and independently. The result of the experiment is a word of length $k$ over the alphabet $[n]$, and all such words have the same probability.

You want to know the probability that the resulting word omits exactly $q$ letters from $[n]$. Therefore we have to count the number of such words. We can select the set $F$ of forbidden letters  in ${n\choose q}$ ways. When this set has been selected an admissible word is then a surjective map $f:\>[k]\to F':=[n]\setminus F$. Such an $f$  induces a partition of the set $[k]$ into $|F'|=n-q$ unlabeled nonempty blocks, which then can be assigned to the elements of $F'$ in $(n-q)!$ ways. The number of such partitions is the [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(k,n-q)$. In all, the number $N_{\rm adm}$ of admissible words then comes to
$$N_{\rm adm}={n\choose q}\>S(k,n-q)\>(n-q)!\ ,$$
and the requested probability $P$ is given by
$$P={N_{\rm adm}\over n^k}\ .$$

Comment: The partitions are assigned to one of the non-forbidden letters, so the k! should be (n-q)!

Comment: Distribute 3 balls over 3 boxes, what is the probability of exactly one box empty? There are 3^3 = 27 possible distriutions, of that 3!=6 where all boxes have one ball, 3 where all balls are in one box, so 18 where 2 boxes have balls. There are 3 possible empty boxes, the balls can be partitioned over the two nonempty boxes in 3 ways, and each partition can be assigned to one of two boxes (n-q)!. 3 * 3 * 2 = 18